# Calculating normalization constant and expected value for this probability density.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

Can someone help me solve this ?

Let $X$ denote a continuous random variable taking values in $(-1,1)$ with density function:

$ f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
        c(1+x)     & -1 < x    \leq 0 \\
        \ c(1-x)  &  0 < x   < 1\\
     \ 0  &  \text{otherwise}\
   \end{cases}
$

$(a)$ Determine the value of $c$

$(b)$ Calculate the expectation value of $(X)$

---

$(a)$ Since $X$ is a density function, $1 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x) \cdot dx = \int_{-1}^{0}c(1+x) \cdot dx + \int_{0}^{1}c(1-x) \cdot dx$. I simplified this and I ended up with $c=1$.

$(b)$ I used $c=1$ assuming $(a)$ is correct.

$E[X] =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x \cdot f_X(x) \cdot dx = \int_{-1}^{0}x(1+x) \cdot dx + \int_{0}^{1}x(1-x) \cdot dx = \frac{-1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} = 0$

Comment: Looks okay to me. For part b, note the density is symmetric about the origin (it is $f(x) = (1-\lvert x \rvert )\mathbb 1_{(-1,1)}(x)$) and has compact support, thus $E X = 0$, no computations needed.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Okay thank you for your help : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers are correct. Here is another solution:

Upon inspection $f(x)=c(1+x)\mathbf 1_{x\in(-1,0)}+c(1-x)\mathbf 1_{x\in(0,1)}$ is comprised of two right triangles with side lengths of $1$ and $c$; thus the area under the curve is $A=1=c/2+c/2\implies c=1$.

Again upon inspection, $EX=\int_{-1}^1 xf(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$, since $EX$ is the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval centered on zero.